# Itext PDF do not display correctly Myanmar Unicode Font

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Itext 5 do not display correctly at generated pdf file for [Myanmar Unicode fonts](https://www.unicode.org/faq/myanmar.html).

**Itext version** : 5.5.13.1

**Expectation Result** : သီဟိုဠ်မှ ဉာဏ်ကြီးရှင်သည်အာယုဝဎ္ဍနဆေးညွှန်းစာကို ဇလွန်ဈေးဘေးဗာဒံပင်ထက် အဓိဋ္ဌာန်လျက် ဂဃနဏဖတ်ခဲ့သည်။

**Actual Result** :

[image]

[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zD1PLaPIlSN7xS2KMPvu2PkPqBAabVSF/view) for generated PDF.

My test string is similar with "The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog" in English. It contains most of Myanmar alphabets.

Java program that I used to product above pdf

```
    String fileName = "sample.pdf";
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, baos);
        writer.setCloseStream(false);

        BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("/fonts/NotoSansMyanmar-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font myanmarUniCodeFont = new Font(unicode, 11, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
        doc.setPageSize(pageSize);
        doc.open();
        String textStr = "သီဟိုဠ်မှ ဉာဏ်ကြီးရှင်သည်အာယုဝဎ္ဍနဆေးညွှန်းစာကို ဇလွန်ဈေးဘေးဗာဒံပင်ထက် အဓိဋ္ဌာန်လျက် ဂဃနဏဖတ်ခဲ့သည်။";
        doc.add(new Paragraph(textStr, myanmarUniCodeFont));
        doc.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,max-age=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(baos.size());
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    baos.close();
```

Ouput texts are correct *(you can copy and paste into a text editors like Notepad++ and see the result)* but wrong display at pdf file.

What should I do to display correctly Myanmar Unicode Font by using itext-pdf-5 ?

Now I'm using dirty way to see the fonts readable. I converted all unicode strings to "Zawgyi Font" *(This is another Myanmar font and [we should never use this](https://my.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%80%9D%E1%80%AE%E1%80%80%E1%80%AE%E1%80%95%E1%80%AE%E1%80%B8%E1%80%92%E1%80%AE%E1%80%B8%E1%80%9A%E1%80%AC%E1%80%B8:Font#Why_not_Zawgyi?).)* and embeded into pdf. This is not good solution and we can't promise all unicodes are correctly converted to Zawgyi-One font string and I don't want to convert unicode texts to non-standard texts. That's why I don't want to use this way.

**Edited about ZawGyi Font with Itext**

Some texts also do not render correctly with itext . Eg : သိန္နီ ၊ ဂွ

Comment: Could you try with iText 7 + pdfCalligraph add-on? pdfCalligraph is required for non-western writing systems with complex ligatures. On https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph you'll find a list of supported writing systems. I'm not a topic expert so I don't know if Myanmar is supported, but it doesn't cost you anything to request a trial. And if you are a customer, then you can submit a feature request for additional writing systems.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thank you for the link sir. I'm wondering about why itext-5 supports to view correctly for non unicode-compliant and not unicode standard language ("Zawgyi One Myanmar Font") while unicode font is not working correctly. This make me feels bad :D.

Comment: I agree @Cataclysm, it is incredibly awkward in iText 5 Legacy and the lack of ligature support was one of the reasons for a rewrite of iText to iText 7. It simply couldn't be done in iText 5 Legacy, not in a clean way that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Full disclosure: I work for iText Software.)

iText 5 does not support proper Unicode based processing of the Myanmar writing system.  Although iText 5 has a specific implementation for Arabic, the inherent limitations of its font infrastructure prevent support for font features that are needed for various other writing systems.

iText 7 improves on this with a new font implementation and an optional module (pdfCalligraph, not open source) to support different writing systems.  However, Myanmar is not (yet) supported.

The corresponding iText 7 code looks like this:

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);
PdfDocument pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document doc = new Document(pdfdoc);

PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/fonts/NotoSansMyanmar-Regular.ttf",
    PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);

String textStr =
    "သီဟိုဠ်မှ ဉာဏ်ကြီးရှင်သည်အာယုဝဎ္ဍနဆေးညွှန်းစာကို ဇလွန်ဈေးဘေးဗာဒံပင်ထက် အဓိဋ္ဌာန်လျက် ဂဃနဏဖတ်ခဲ့သည်။";
// Explicit writing system
//doc.add(new Paragraph(textStr).setFont(f).setFontScript(Character.UnicodeScript.MYANMAR));
// Rely on autodetection
doc.add(new Paragraph(textStr).setFont(f));
doc.close();
```

Regardless whether pdfCalligraph is used or not, the rendering is still wrong:

[image: Wrong Myanmar rendering]

If a commercial license is an option for you, please submit this feature request.  Additional writing systems are still actively added.  If not, I'm afraid this will not be possible with iText and you'll have to find another solution.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation about it is not possible with itext 5. I thought itext will correctly render unicode texts regardless of writing systems like browsers do to html contents.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. But I used thymeleaf with iText. I use the ttf font package of the language (not unicode) and use the converter to convert unicode to my language and attach it into the PDF as normal string. it works like a charm. if you have the possibility to use thymeleaf, try this approach.

put below CSS inside the style tag.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont-family';
    src: url('/fonts/myfont.ttf');
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

.mylanguage{
    font-family: 'myfontfamily';
}

<p class="mylanguage">your converted font text</p>
```

Java code to generate pdf.

```
context.setVariable("myvariable", myvariable);
String html = templateEngine.process("mypdf", context);
html = templateEngine.process("mythymeleaf", context);
String fileName = "myfile.pdf";
PDFEncryption pdfEncryption  = new PDFEncryption();
String password = "0000";
pdfEncryption.setUserPassword(password.getBytes());

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
renderer.layout();
renderer.setPDFEncryption(pdfEncryption);
renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Here is the link for this full tutorial about this approach with working source code.
https://medium.com/@natsucoder/create-pdf-in-different-language-fonts-using-spring-boot-thymeleaf-itext-cba7f8612c61

Comment: What are related things to pdf file with **thymeleaf** and **css** ?

Comment: As I said, this is a different approach to solve your problem. CSS to load TTF font file and thymeleaf use to read your content and convert it into your language.

Comment: I think you can use the same approach without using thymeleaf as well. The only different is that you can't use unicode. I also did the same as you did with my own application with unicode and face the same error. some letters are crossing and looking weird. Try to use native font file without using unicode style font.

Comment: Now I understand .. you are trying to convert html content string from thymeleaf template to pdf content. Can you complete more code examples because I can't figure it out which classes are from which libraires ? Let me try with your code examples and if it is work , I will accept this as answer and question's bounties will be yours. I am using with springboot and which location should I place for my font file ? Thanks in advance. I'd really appreciated your suggestions.

Comment: I update my answer with link. Maybe that will help you out.

Comment: I've tested with your code and the output is the same as my question (Texts are not correctly rendered). Can you try with OP's texts ?

Comment: if you change the html file to UTF-8 encoding, then this approach will not work. The font you have to use should provide alpha-numeric characters. As the tutorial suggests, the html content has to be normal alpha-numeric characters. I worked with two different languages to generate PDF and it works perfectly fine. if you can't type your font without using any special characters, i think this is not helpful for you.

Comment: probably your texts could be provided by itext while mine is not working properly by itext.